# Pandas - merging rows under certain conditions

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have a table in this form:

| Cat A | Cat B | Year | Area | Names |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | C | 2012 | 1 | A |
| A | D | 2012 | 2 | B |
| A | D | 2013 | 3 | C |
| A | D | 2013 | 4 | D |
| B | D | 2013 | 5 | E |
| B | C | 2013 | 6 | F |

And I would like to merge rows if they share the same values in Cat A, Cat B, and Year, such that the merged row will have the sum of the values in the Area column, and a comma separated list from the Names column. The result should look like this:

| Cat A | Cat B | Year | Area | Names |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | C | 2012 | 1 | A |
| A | D | 2012 | 2 | B |
| A | D | 2013 | **7** | **C,D** |
| B | D | 2013 | 5 | E |
| B | C | 2013 | 6 | F |

I tried the line:

```
df.groupby(["Cat A","Cat B", "Year"])
```

But got stuck after that... how should I continue?

Comment: `df.groupby(["Cat A","Cat B", "Year"]).agg(area=('area','sum'),names=('name', ','.join))` very close you need to apply your aggregation

Answer (score 1):

With [`df.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and [`.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html):

```
out = (df.groupby(["Cat A","Cat B", "Year"], sort=False, as_index=False)
       .agg({'Area':sum,'Names':','.join}))

out

  Cat A Cat B  Year  Area Names
0     A     C  2012     1     A
1     A     D  2012     2     B
2     A     D  2013     7   C,D
3     B     D  2013     5     E
4     B     C  2013     6     F
```